# How to execute a script that has argparse from within a second script

Tags: python, parameter-passing, argparse

I have this simple script named `test1.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from argparse import ArgumentParser


def cmdlineparse():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-tid", dest="CHEMBL_TARGET_ID", required=True, type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-molfile", dest="XTEST_MOLFILE", required=False, type=str)

    args=parser.parse_args()
    return args


if __name__ == '__main__':

    args = cmdlineparse()

    print("The given CHEMBL_TARGET_ID is %s" % args.CHEMBL_TARGET_ID)
    print("The given XTEST_MOLFILE is %s" % args.XTEST_MOLFILE)
```

Normally, I execute it like this `./test1.py -tid CHEMBL8868 -molfile ligands.sdf`.

What I want to do is to execute it multiple times from within a second script named `test2.py`. The simplest solution would be to call it using  `subprocess.call` or something equivalent.

```
subprocess.call("./test1.py -tid CHEMBL8868 -molfile ligands.sdf".split(), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

However, I would like to do it in a more elegant way, namely by importing it as a module and passing values to `argparse`. Could someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: `parse_args()` gets values from list `sys.argv` but you can use own list `parse_args(my_list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to refactor your script a bit: let `cmdlineparse` take an list of arguments to parse, and define a function `main` that does the actual work instead of a bare block guarded by `__main__`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from argparse import ArgumentParser


def cmdlineparse(args):
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-tid", dest="CHEMBL_TARGET_ID", required=True, type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-molfile", dest="XTEST_MOLFILE", required=False, type=str)

    args=parser.parse_args(args)
    return args

def main(args=None):
    args = cmdlineparse(args)
    print("The given CHEMBL_TARGET_ID is %s" % args.CHEMBL_TARGET_ID)
    print("The given XTEST_MOLFILE is %s" % args.XTEST_MOLFILE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Without an argument, `main` will parse the current command-line arguments, since a value of `None` passed (eventually) to `parser.parse_args()` will cause it to parse `sys.argv[1:]`.

Now you can import `test1` and call `main` explicitly as often as you like:

```
import test1

test1.main(["-tid", "CHEMBL8868", "-molfile", "ligands.sdf"])
test1.main(["-tid", "CHEMBL8293", "-molfile", "stuff.sdf"])
# etc
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the print statements within `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: You can put anything you want there; there's really nothing special about it, aside from the "magic" that sets the value of `__name__` in the first place.

Comment: I mean that prints were just an example. I have to transfer all the execution code under the main() definition otherwise nothing is executed.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The point is that outside the `if` block, you *only* have function definitions and (maybe) variable definitions. You can call `main` (as the entry point) in the `if` block so that `test1` can still be used as a script, but if you *import* `test1` as a regular module, none of the defined functions are called unless you call them explicitly.

Comment: OK, I will move all execution code inside main() then.