# Generating and passing args at runtime to a second script that uses argparse

Tags: python, parameter-passing, argparse

I have a script (A) that uses argparse to parse comand line args, I am writing script (B) that will generate various combinations of arguments for script A at runtime and call the main method of A.

I cannot modify script A.

**Script A**

```
import argparse

def main():
    args = code_to_add_args().parse_args()
    # does stuff with args
```

**Script B**

```
import argparse
from A import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_cli_args = code_to_add_args().parse_args()
    new_args_generated_at_runtime = generate_args()
    main() # pass new_args_generated_at_runtime into A to be parsed by argparse
```

How do I use script B to supply CLI args to script A without modifying script A?

The closest I have found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982901/how-to-execute-a-script-that-has-argparse-from-within-a-second-script), but its answer requires modifying the script A.

If possible I would prefer not to use `subprocess.call()`

Comment: You can either modify the `sys.argv` list that `parse_args` normally parses, or provide a custom list of strings.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#beyond-sys-argv

Comment: Thank you. So since I cannot modify the parameter of parse_args() in script A, would you suggest something like as follows: ```sys.argv.append("--arg=value")```?

Comment: Yes.  You may need to remove or replace some strings depending on what's already there, and what the A parser can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) led me to a solution that worked.

I cleared sys.argv and then appended my args to it:

**Script A**

```
import argparse

def main():
    args = code_to_add_args().parse_args()
    # does stuff with args
```

**Script B**

```
import argparse
from A import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_cli_args = code_to_add_args().parse_args()

    new_args_list = generate_list_of_args()
    # Keep the first element of sys.argv to retain the name of the script
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]

    for param in new_args_list:
        sys.argv.append(param)

    main() # Now new args have been added to sys.argv, argparse in script A will use them.
```